# Change Attribute X if Attribute Y changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I am familiar with Dirty Objects and using `attribute_changed?` in a presave callback. I'd like to change one attribute back to a default value when the attribute Y is changed. So in pseudocode:

```
def pre_save
  self.crawl_mode = false if self.url_changed?
end
```

However, changing the url and trying to save fails. It still passes all validations, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are you doing this on `before_validation` or `before_save`?

Comment: This is on `before_save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.crawl_mode = false` will cause the method to return `false` which will abort the save.

try this:

```
def pre_save
  self.crawl_mode = false if self.url_changed?
  true
end
```

Ruby methods implicitly return the value of the last assignment (more precisely, last expression)